# How to check if the Snake in a snake game has crossed the food?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am working on a snake game using python and pygame but having problem in checking whether the snake has crossed the food or not. Can anyone here help me with that?

I've tried making the location of food to be a multiple of 10 since  my snake width and height is also 10 and the window (width and height) is also a multiple of 10.

```py
food_x = random.randrange(0, displayWidth-foodWidth, 10)
food_y = random.randrange(0, displayHeight-foodHeight, 10)
```

I expected that doing so will make the location of the food such that there will be no collisions but direct overlap of snake and food which would make the coding easier. However, there were collisions also.

Comment: How are you defining your "snake" - a bunch of rectangles?  Does it only eat from the head-end?

Comment: Yeah I did the same thing. Can you help me with collision detection?  @Kingsley

Answer (score 3):

So given your snake data structure is a set of rectangles, and the snake only "eats" from the head-rectangle, it's pretty simple to determine a collision routine.

The PyGame [rect library](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) has functions for [checking collisions](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) between rectangles.

So assuming `head_rect` is a `rect` with the co-ordinates and size of your snake's head, and `food_rect` is an item to check:

```
if ( head_rect.colliderect( food_rect ) ):
    # TODO - consume food
```

Or if there's a list of `food_rect` in `food_list`:

```
def hitFood( head_rect, food_list ):
    """ Given a head rectangle, and a list of food rectangles, return 
        the first item in the list that overlaps the list items.  
        Return None for a no-hit """
    food_hit = None
    collide_index = head_rect.collidelist( food_list )
    if ( collide_index != -1 ):
        # snake hit something
        food_hit = food_list.pop( collide_index )
    return food_hit
```

It's *much* easier to use PyGame's libraries rectangle overlap functions than making your own.